# Is it possible to use Umbraco authentication via REST api for a .Net Core application? I understand that Umbraco itself is not .Net core compliant

Tags: authentication, umbraco7, user-management

I would like to use an existing Umbraco implementation. The only thing I need out of it is to use the user management and authentication in it to serve for the new set of .Net core APIs we wish to write. Is this something that is possible? If yes, what is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with Umbraco Headless.

Read more about Umbraco Headless here: https://umbraco.com/products/umbraco-headless/

Alternatively, you can build your own Umbraco solution and expose its methods with ApiControllers.

You can read much more about Umbraco API Controllers here: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Routing/WebApi/